# Массив строк в качестве входного параметра java функции

Tags: java, массивы, процедуры

Возник следующий вопрос: есть следующая процедура

```
public void concatenateTermsOfGroupsOfFiles()
```

в качестве входного параметра, которой будет

```
String[] ConcatPaths = new String[CountComputers];
```

Каким образом нужно объявить эту процедуру?

Comment: извините, вы прикалываетесь что ли?

Comment: @DreamChild, ну ты что не потерпишь до 21.05.13?

Comment: @Gorets я может, туплю под вечер, но что все-таки случится 21-го? Что ТС грозится начать проверять?

Comment: @DreamChild, видимо ТС получит зарплату и купит новый комп, на который поставит JDK.

Comment: @avp тем не менее, хэшкод - не лучшая замена компилятору

Comment: @DreamChild, компилятор тут все равно не поможет. Достаточно на имя

    concatenationOfTermsOfGroupsOfFiles

посмотреть.

Answer (score 3):

`public void concatenationOfTermsOfGroupsOfFiles(String[] concatPaths);`

Comment: не, ты не прав =) так не учатся, потому что следующий вопрос должен быть "а как мне вернуть параметр с этой процедуры?"